# How to fix lstm and cnn code for MNIST handwriting dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm coding LSTM+CNN in one code for MNIST handwriting dataset, how can solve dimensions issue?

I coded LSTM and CNN separately for MNIST handwriting dataset, but merging has issues

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

################### Loading dataset ##########################
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1))
x_test = x_test.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))

################### Normalizing dataset ######################
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

################### Building a model #########################
ConvNN_model = models.Sequential()

ConvNN_model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

ConvNN_model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

ConvNN_model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
ConvNN_model.add(Dropout(0.2))

ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

################### Compiling a model ########################
ConvNN_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

################### Fitting a model ##########################
ConvNN_model.fit(x = x_train, 
          y = y_train, 
          epochs = 1, 
          validation_data = (x_test, y_test))
```

I got this issue:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>        in ()
>            23 ConvNN_model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
>            24 
>       ---> 25 ConvNN_model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
>            26 ConvNN_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
>            27
>
> ```
> ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_7 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 11,11, 64]
> ```

Could you please help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Abdel, what is the sequence here that you are trying to run LSTM over?

Comment: Hi Mohsin, actually I need this code to be fixed under any LSTM sequence as I'm new in this area and I need a correct code for LSTM+CNN as I did both of them separately. Could you please help me in this ?

Answer (score -1):

The trick here is to use [`TimeDistributed`](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) . As you have sequences in both row and column directions, one of them needs to be encoded first. Below we first encode rows using LSTM wrapped in TimeDistributed and then use LSTM to encode columns.

```
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense, TimeDistributed
################### Building a model #########################
ConvNN_model = models.Sequential()

ConvNN_model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

ConvNN_model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

# encode rows of matrix
ConvNN_model.add(TimeDistributed(LSTM(128, activation='relu')))
ConvNN_model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# encode columns
ConvNN_model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))

ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))
ConvNN_model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

################### Compiling a model ########################
ConvNN_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

################### Fitting a model ##########################
ConvNN_model.fit(x = x_train, 
          y = y_train, 
          epochs = 1, 
          validation_data = (x_test, y_test))
```